# Using LINQ to Assert Values in a Database

Tags: c#, linq, nunit, integration-testing, sqlconnection

I am storing data into a database by calling a function, `StoreData`.  In the designer code, a `SqlConnection` is open, `SqlCommand`s are run, and the `SqlConnection` closes. After `StoreData` is run succesfully, data is stored in the DB.

I would like to run an integration test to `StoreData` by asserting that a value that I chose for the integration test (before `StoreData` runs, ie. `id = 0, time = "13:00"`) is equal to the value found in the DB (after `StoreData` runs, ie. `id` column = `0` and `time_stamp` column = `"13:00"`).

I thought about using LINQ. Is this a good approach, or is there a better approach to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, this is an integration test, and it's perfectly valid to make a test that will read the data back out of the database and ensure it looks correct.

However, if you want to make it a unit test, what you should do is mock the backing mechanism to be some kind of in memory structure, and then your `StoreData` method would insert into this structure instead of calling the database. Typically then, that would mean making some kind of factory mechanism for `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` and then overloading methods to make sure the query gets targeted to your in memory structure.

Comment: I had initially suspected this as an integration test.  I understand mocking for unit-testing. For integration testing, do you have insight on how to read the data from the DB (using LINQ or something else)? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, you could use whatever established loading mechanism you have. If you're testing the save, you're not testing the load. So you can test the save code, and then load it with your code that would get the element and check the values.

Comment: That gives me a plan of attack. Thanks.

Comment: What works well for us. Say we want to test a method which retrieves a customer by their ID from the DB as expected. We add a record using standard ADO.NET. Then execute the method to retrieve a specific record by ID, passing the ID from our sample record. Then we assert that the record retrieved is in fact the record we expected. Then we clean up and using ADO.NET, we delete the test record again from the database. The integration test project has it's own config file with the correct connection string. This is just one of many ways you might do an integration test.